# What is the Action of #define in this Instance?

Tags: c++, c, function, shell

As part of my homework, I've been given this code to help with the task they've given us... to create a basic shell that supports piping, background processes, and a number of builtin commands, etc. I've read through the code they've given us for parsing...

I'm familiar with the `#define` keyword in C, however, I've not seen it used like in the below code: namely, what is `c` for? I'm guessing it has been assigned to mean a character but I'm not sure:

```
#define PIPE  ('|')
#define BG    ('&')
#define RIN   ('<')
#define RUT   ('>')

#define ispipe(c) ((c) == PIPE)
#define isbg(c)   ((c) == BG)
#define isrin(c)  ((c) == RIN)
#define isrut(c)  ((c) == RUT)
#define isspec(c) (ispipe(c) || isbg(c) || isrin(c) || isrut(c))
```

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last five `#define` statements you give define ***macros***, each taking an ***argument***, which is here always called `c`. Your first four `#define` statements are also, technically, macros, but they don't need an argument - they are simply substituted for their 'values' when encountered; frequently, programmers refer to macros with no argument as *tokens*, with the `PIPE` token here having a token value of `('|')`.

Later on in the file (possibly) there will be cases where one or more of these macros is called, and that call will have a value for the *actual* argument, like this, for example:

```
if (ispipe(test_arg)) ++npipes;
```

This macro "call" will be replaced (by the pre-processor) with the following expansion:

```
if (((test) == ('|')) ++npipes;
```

And, similarly, for the other #define XXX(c) macros.

*Note: It is quite common to add (lots of) parentheses in macro definitions, just to be sure that the code does what you 'think' it will after the pre-processor has done its stuff.*

Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

Comment: The terminology used in the C standard is that the first four `#define` statements define *object-like* macros and the last five define *function-like* macros. While the name of the macro is a token in the C grammar, I have never heard a programmer refer to the macro (not just its name) as a token.

Comment: @EricPostpischil   Maybe the usage is (or was) colloquial to where and/or with whom I developed my C/C++ programming technique. But also see: https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=0i6XXZTJCpWgvQTpuILAAQ&q=token+dictionary&oq=token+diction&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0j0i22i30l9.130614.134614..135636...2.5..0.120.1617.4j11......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i273j0i131j0i67j0i10j33i160.ZVo4iE7V3_s

Comment: @Adrian: The meaning 3 of the linked definition is how both I and Eric (and presumably the majority of programmers) understand the word "token" in this context. `PIPE` _is_ a token, but so are `3`, `+`, `(` and `printf` — it doesn't have anything to do with whether they are a macro or not.

Answer (score 3):

`#define` is not a function, it is a *preprocessor directive*.

`c` could be anything. If you write `ispipe(42)`, then the preprocessor will change it into `((42) == PIPE)`. If you write `ispipe(while(1);)`, then the preprocessor will change it into `((while(1);) == PIPE)`, which will dumbfound the compiler when it reads it.

The preprocessor is blind, and does not know much about C syntax, and nothing of its semantics; the only way to understand what `c` is supposed to be is either to reverse-engineer the intended usage, or to ask whoever wrote the code without comments to tell you what they meant.

After the edit, it is rather reasonable to expect that `c` should be a `char`, in order to be meaningfully compared to `'|'` and similar. But even passing `0xDEADBEEF` should compile correctly (returning `FALSE`).

Comment: It is not correct that the preprocessor does not know anything about C syntax. It knows enough syntax to recognize preprocessing tokens of the C syntax (such as identifiers, constants, string literals, and punctuation), and it works by replacing preprocessing tokens, not text.

Comment: @Amadan: The syntax of preprocessing tokens is formally part of C, per the 2018 C standard and preceding versions. It is defined in clause 6.4 of the standard, and errors arise during preprocessing if the syntactical rules are violated. Preprocessing is also formally part of C and is defined in clause 610. This can be observed if one tries to use the preprocessor alone (as with `gcc -x c -E`) to process a non-C file. For example, `#define cannot can't` will produce an error.